# STM32 Software Interrupt Trigger Any

Tags: stm32, arm, interrupts, cortex-m7

STM32F746-Disco
Windows 10
STM32CubeIDE 1.8.0

I've just finished writing my first minimal bare metal UART DMA driver (CMSIS only), and both reception and transmission work ok, but then I thought I wanted to make a nice demo program of it, and it would require software-triggered interrupt. I have never used one before (not that it ever stopped me), but I have no problem with software interrupt in terms of how to activate it or clear flags, since I already wrote an interrupt-based driver for UART as well, and all the info is in the reference & programming manuals.

However, I got curious in one specific thing about it: I can literally trigger any IRQn Handler via software by setting the IRQn value in NVIC's STIR register. But there are no dedicated interrupts to be triggered exclusively by software, they all belong to some peripherals. I want an ISR to be triggered exclusively by software.

In my little DMA-based UART demo program I'm definitely not going to use, say, CAN2_TX_IRQn, then I can use it for my software-triggered interrupt.    Is it correct? I believe I'm right, but it never hurts to make thing clear.

**EDIT:** **I tested it. Yes**, I used CAN2_TX_IRQ for my exclusively-software-triggered interrupt. Now I can trigger UART to send data via DMA whenever it finished receiving data with DMA. Question closed.

(but I can't close my own question, so I will wait until someone does it or there is an answer I can accept)

Comment: Sounds like XY problem to me. What is it that you want to achieve? How would a "software interrupt" help you?

Comment: @Armandas what's XY about it? Can I use arbitrary IRQn for software interrupt or not? That's all the question. As for why, well, it would make my little demo program nice for demonstration. It's very minimalist. No super algorithm or purpose.

Comment: If you want software triggered interrupt, there's the SWI opcode, is that what you want?

Comment: I'm asking because I thought that there may be a better way to achieve the same goal. Anyway, have a look at this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752151/which-cortex-m3-interrupts-can-i-use-for-general-purpose-work

Comment: @Armandas that is actually helpful and interesting. Thank you for relevant information I didn't even know about

Comment: @Armandas it looks like I can't enable/disable/clear pending PendSV_IRQn via NVIC_Enable, because NVIC functions make a check for IRQn to be >=0 (while PendSV has -2). And I can't google out how to do actually do it in code. I mean, I can always edit core_cm7.h to allow NVIC_Enable/disable/clear_flag for IRQn=-2, I just thought there is some normal way to do it (most answers everywhere involve writing directly to NVIC registers via their full numeric register address, without definitions or wrappers, which I can utilize by taking the address of the registers too, still a little weird)

Comment: Alternative solution to PendSV: I used CAN2_TX_IRQn, which I renamed by creating my own enum with SoftwareIRQn = CAN2_TX_IRQn; also, I made #define SoftwareIRQnHandler(void) CAN2_TX_IRQHandler(void). Now I can simply use SoftwareIRQn and SoftwareIRQnHandler function, and easily set priorities with standard NVIC functions without editing core_m7.h.